# How to call class method inside a Laravel view?

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to find a way to call a method from within my class file inside a blade file. `foo()` uses the `$item` variable from the foreach loop. Since I'm looping inside the blade file, I'm unable, or rather, it's bad practise, to call a controller method inside a view, or so I've heard.

MyController

```
public function getData() {
  $data = DB::paginate(10);
  return view('view', ['data' => $data]);
}

public function foo($var) {
 //do something with $var
 return $var
}
```

view.blade.php

```
@foreach ($data as $item)

 <td>{{$item->key}}</td>
 <td>{{ //myController::foo($item) is Essentially the output I need }} </td>

@endforeach
```

Since `$item` is generated in the `foreach` (which is inside the view), I don't know how to call method **before** it's past to the view in the return statement.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just share your controller with your view:

Controller:

```
public function getData() {
    $data = DB::paginate(10);

    return view('view', [
        'data' => $data, 
        'controller' => $this,
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($data as $item)

 <td>{{$item->key}}</td>
 <td>{{ $controller->foo($item) }} </td>

@endforeach
```

The better way would be to generate the output in the controller:

```
public function getData() {
    $data = DB::paginate(10);

    $data = array_map(function($item) {
        $item->output = $this->foo($item);

        return $item;
    }, $data);

    return view('view', [
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That's great. What about if were to reference a helper file that has a class in it? Let's say @ `App\Helpers\Helper.php`

Comment: If I understand you correctly: Just instantiate the class and share it with the view: $helper = new \App\Helpers\Helper(); ... return view('view', ['helper' => $helper]);